# sql query to artificially create rows

Tags: sql

I have a piece of code that runs on a variety of databases. It simply runs a configurable sql query which returns a number of rows. From each row, i pull some text and a number to create a new object. Our latest client has decided to put all the text number combinations in a single row of the database i.e

```
 text_1, num_1, text_2, num_2, text_3, num_3
```

Is there a clever way I can query this to return

```
 text_1,num_1
 text_2,num_2
 text_3,num_3
```

so that I don't have to re-code the section for this client.

EDIT:
(Different databases means different RDBMS) 
(the commas delimit different columns within a table)

Comment: Is each row a single string, or are you using `,` to indicate separate fields?  Also, when you say a variety of databases, do you mean different RDBMS for each?  Or just different physical instances, but all using the same RDBMS?

Comment: @Dems - updated the question to answer your queries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT
  CASE row.id WHEN 1 THEN field1
              WHEN 2 THEN field3
                     ELSE field5
  END                                        AS new_field_1,
  CASE row.id WHEN 1 THEN field2
              WHEN 2 THEN field4
                     ELSE field6
  END                                        AS new_field_2
FROM
  myTable
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) AS row
```

This should work for most, though still need a little modification (Such as adding 'FROM dual' in the UNIONs for Oracle...)

Alternatively, just UNION three queries together...

```
SELECT field1, field2 FROM myTable
UNION ALL
SELECT field3, field4 FROM myTable
UNION ALL
SELECT field5, field6 FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function/SP to return a ResultSet the way you need.

Comment: It has to run across different RDBMS systems so needs to use a very generic subset of SQL